# Using SimpleCov in a Ruby Project

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, code-coverage

I am trying to use the simplecov gem in a Ruby project. However I have failed miserably. Here is what I've done until now.

My project structure is:
ProjectFolder
  - lib
  - test

I have my tests in test and source code in lib. I have created a test_helper.rb in the test directory and added the following.

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start
```

Then I put `require 'test/test_helper.rb' in every test file. What happened was it sometimes created some report, and sometimes didn't. And when it did it was inconsistent.

All the tutorials I found was for Rails so I turn to StackOverflow once more, to show me the way.

Comment: You have this above any other requires?  You are also running all tests to get the report that you are looking for?  If you run individual tests, it will only track those lines that are covered by that test, so that would not be surprising.

Comment: ok i think the first part was important. I had it all the way at the bottom of requires. I finally created a test suite for all the tests to run together and it worked. thanks. if you can write this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rcov/SimpleCov will only report the coverage of the tests ran.

For a full coverage report, you must ensure that the full test suite is ran as the last test, to build a full coverage report.

You will also want to make sure it is the first require in your test_helper.rb file.

From the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/simplecov/frames):

> Note: If SimpleCov starts after your application code is already
>   loaded (via require), it won't be able to track your files and their
>   coverage! The SimpleCov.start must be issued before any of your
>   application code is required!

Comment: I am using SimpleCov but basically the logic is the same. Thanks for the answer